# Using XML PATH to concatenate results from multiple WHERE clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I know barely enough SQL to get by. I'm trying to get MS SQL to display a recordset that an application can directly walk through with little parsing.

The database is structured as follows:

- A table of customers
- A table of TechContacts
- A table of Services
- A table of Sites
- Each entry in TechContact is FK back to Customer
- Each Entry is FK to Customer and Service
- Each service can be linked to one or many Sites from multiple customers.

So if I want to get a list of email addresses that are linked to a particular Service, and get my results set just using INNER JOIN, it would look like this:

```
SELECT tc.emailaddress as 'Email Address', s.sitename as 'Affected Site', c.CustomerName as 'Customer Name'
FROM techcontact as tc
INNER JOIN customer as c
on tc.customernumber = c.customernumber
INNER JOIN site as s
on c.customernumber = s.customernumber
INNER JOIN dbo.service as serv
on s.serviceid = serv.serviceid
INNER JOIN sitetype as st
on s.sitetype = st.SiteTypeID

where serv.servicename = 'Service 1'
and st.SiteTypeID = 1
and s.enabled = 1
order by s.SiteName asc
```

Will give me a row for each email address:

```
Email Address           Site Affected   Customer Name
email1@customer1.com    Site A          1
email1@customer2.com    Site B          2
email2@customer2.com    Site B          2
email3@customer2.com    Site B          2
email1@customer3.com    Site C          3
email2@customer3.com    Site C          3
email1@customer3.com    Site D          3
email2@customer3.com    Site D          3
```

After some searching, I found an answer for a similar question that used XML PATH to concatenate the results. This is the query I used to get a working solution:

```
Select distinct c.customernumber, 
substring(

    (
        Select ';'+tc.emailaddress  AS [text()]
        From dbo.techcontact tc
        Where tc.customernumber = c.customernumber
        For XML PATH ('')
    ), 2, 1000) [Emails],
substring(

    (
        Select distinct ', '+s.SiteName  AS [text()]
        From dbo.Site s
        inner join service
        on s.serviceid = serv.serviceid
        where (serv.servicename = 'service 1' )
        and s.SiteType = 1
        and s.CustomerNumber = c.CustomerNumber
        For XML PATH ('')
    ), 2, 1000) [Sites]
From dbo.customer c
INNER JOIN site as s
on c.customernumber = s.customernumber
INNER JOIN dbo.service as serv
on s.serviceid = serv.serviceid
INNER JOIN dbo.TechContact as tc
on tc.CustomerNumber = c.CustomerNumber
where (serv.servicename = 'service 1')
and s.SiteType = 1
```

Which give me this result: which is PERFECT:

```
Customer  Sites             Email
1         Site A            email1@customer1.com
2         Site B            email1@customer2.com;email2@customer2.com;email3@customer2.com
3         Site C, Site D    email1@customer3.com;email2@customer3.com
```

However if I want to get the results from multiple Services by entering the OR in the two WHERE statements lines like so

```
where (serv.servicename = 'service 1' or serv.servicename = 'service 2' )
```

Then the result will not concatenate where there are two sites from the same customer in different services:

```
Customer    Site            Email
1           Site A          email1@customer1.com
1           Site E          email1@customer1.com
2           Site B          email1@customer2.com;email2@customer2.com;email3@customer2.com
3           Site C, Site D  email1@customer3.com;email2@customer3.com
```

I'm not too sure why it isn't concatenating? I think I might be doing the WHERE's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting around it by inserting the entire results set into another table using a table variable, and then using XML PATH to select from that. It adds an extra step which I was hoping to avoid, but the end result is what I want.

The query:

```
-- Drop the table before we attempt to use it.
IF OBJECT_ID('zzz1', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE zzz1
GO

--Table variable will be inserted in via a form, called @AffectedServices, but for the sake of testing we will insert them here.
declare @AffectedServices table
(
    ServiceName varchar(1000)
)
insert into @AffectedServices values ('Service 1')
insert into @AffectedServices values ('Service 2')
insert into @AffectedServices values ('Service 3')

--select into the new table. The table has some primary keys that don't get displayed.
select c.customernumber, s.CustomerNumber as 'sCustomerNumber', s.sitename, tc.CustomerNumber as 'tcCustomerNumber', tc.emailaddress
into zzz1
FROM TechContact as tc
INNER JOIN customer as c
    on tc.customernumber = c.customernumber
INNER JOIN site as s
    on c.customernumber = s.customernumber
INNER JOIN dbo.service as serv
    on s.serviceid = serv.serviceid
INNER JOIN sitetype as st
    on s.sitetype = st.SiteTypeID
INNER JOIN @AffectedServices as AfSe
 on serv.ServiceName = AfSe.ServiceName
WHERE serv.servicename = AfSe.ServiceName
and st.SiteTypeID = 1

--Now we can concatenate the results without using extra WHERE/OR clauses.
Select T1.Customernumber
    , Stuff(
        (
        Select distinct ', ' + T2.SiteName
        From zzz1 As T2
        Where T2.CustomerNumber = T1.CustomerNumber
        --Order By T2.SiteName
        For Xml Path(''), type
        ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') As Sites
         , Stuff(
         (
        Select distinct ', ' + T2.EmailAddress
        From zzz1 As T2
        Where T2.CustomerNumber = T1.CustomerNumber
        --Order By T2.EmailAddress
        For Xml Path(''), type
        ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') As EmailAddresses
From zzz1 As T1
Group By T1.CustomerNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not optimal, but it will solve your problem:

```
Select distinct c.customernumber, 
substring(

(
    Select ';'+tc.emailaddress  AS [text()]
    From dbo.techcontact tc
    Where tc.customernumber = c.customernumber
    For XML PATH ('')
), 2, 1000) [Emails],
substring(

    (
        Select distinct ', '+s.SiteName  AS [text()]
        From dbo.Site s
        inner join service
        on s.serviceid = serv.serviceid
        where (serv.servicename = 'service 1' )
        and s.SiteType = 1
        and s.CustomerNumber = c.CustomerNumber
        For XML PATH ('')
    ), 2, 1000) [Sites]
From dbo.customer c
INNER JOIN site as s
on c.customernumber = s.customernumber
INNER JOIN dbo.service as serv
on s.serviceid = serv.serviceid
INNER JOIN dbo.TechContact as tc
on tc.CustomerNumber = c.CustomerNumber
where (serv.servicename = 'service 1' AND serv.servicename = 'service 2')
and s.SiteType = 1)
UNION
Select distinct c.customernumber, 
substring(

(
    Select ';'+tc.emailaddress  AS [text()]
    From dbo.techcontact tc
    Where tc.customernumber = c.customernumber
    For XML PATH ('')
), 2, 1000) [Emails],
substring(

    (
        Select distinct ', '+s.SiteName  AS [text()]
        From dbo.Site s
        inner join service
        on s.serviceid = serv.serviceid
        where (serv.servicename = 'service 1' )
        and s.SiteType = 1
        and s.CustomerNumber = c.CustomerNumber
        For XML PATH ('')
    ), 2, 1000) [Sites]
From dbo.customer c
INNER JOIN site as s
on c.customernumber = s.customernumber
INNER JOIN dbo.service as serv
on s.serviceid = serv.serviceid
INNER JOIN dbo.TechContact as tc
on tc.CustomerNumber = c.CustomerNumber
where (serv.servicename = 'service 1')
and s.SiteType = 1
Except (Select distinct c.customernumber, 
substring(

(
    Select ';'+tc.emailaddress  AS [text()]
    From dbo.techcontact tc
    Where tc.customernumber = c.customernumber
    For XML PATH ('')
), 2, 1000) [Emails],
substring(

    (
        Select distinct ', '+s.SiteName  AS [text()]
        From dbo.Site s
        inner join service
        on s.serviceid = serv.serviceid
        where (serv.servicename = 'service 1' )
        and s.SiteType = 1
        and s.CustomerNumber = c.CustomerNumber
        For XML PATH ('')
    ), 2, 1000) [Sites]
From dbo.customer c
INNER JOIN site as s
on c.customernumber = s.customernumber
INNER JOIN dbo.service as serv
on s.serviceid = serv.serviceid
INNER JOIN dbo.TechContact as tc
on tc.CustomerNumber = c.CustomerNumber
where (serv.servicename = 'service 1' AND serv.servicename = 'service 2')
and s.SiteType = 1) )
UNION
       Select distinct ', '+s.SiteName  AS [text()]
        From dbo.Site s
        inner join service
        on s.serviceid = serv.serviceid
        where (serv.servicename = 'service 1' )
        and s.SiteType = 1
        and s.CustomerNumber = c.CustomerNumber
        For XML PATH ('')
    ), 2, 1000) [Sites]
From dbo.customer c
INNER JOIN site as s
on c.customernumber = s.customernumber
INNER JOIN dbo.service as serv
on s.serviceid = serv.serviceid
INNER JOIN dbo.TechContact as tc
on tc.CustomerNumber = c.CustomerNumber
where (serv.servicename = 'service 2')
and s.SiteType = 1
Except  (Select distinct c.customernumber, 
substring(

(
    Select ';'+tc.emailaddress  AS [text()]
    From dbo.techcontact tc
    Where tc.customernumber = c.customernumber
    For XML PATH ('')
), 2, 1000) [Emails],
substring(

    (
        Select distinct ', '+s.SiteName  AS [text()]
        From dbo.Site s
        inner join service
        on s.serviceid = serv.serviceid
        where (serv.servicename = 'service 1' )
        and s.SiteType = 1
        and s.CustomerNumber = c.CustomerNumber
        For XML PATH ('')
    ), 2, 1000) [Sites]
From dbo.customer c
INNER JOIN site as s
on c.customernumber = s.customernumber
INNER JOIN dbo.service as serv
on s.serviceid = serv.serviceid
INNER JOIN dbo.TechContact as tc
on tc.CustomerNumber = c.CustomerNumber
where (serv.servicename = 'service 1' AND serv.servicename = 'service 2')
and s.SiteType = 1) )
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't think the syntax of 'AS table1' is correct?

Comment: Yeah, i thought so :/ you can copy the whole first query instead of using table1 and see if it works. Otherwise i'll look at that tommorow since im in bed atm :p